# Writing automated test cases for electron app build with electron react boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, automated-tests, electron

I have just started to build a cross-platform app with electron along with react for that purpose, I have used electron react boilerplate for simplicity and set the standard to my app.

Where i face problem in writing some automated test cases is, there is already a test folder inside application root, which basically does unit testing and component testing. As it is said that, it is best practice to use spectron along with mocha and chai. What is the best possible way to set up them for automated testing?

I have already installed spectron with mocha and used the testing code provided in (https://github.com/electron/spectron#application-api) official documentation of the electron.But where i was stuck is in providing path i.e.

```
args: [path.join(__dirname, '..')]
```

As it supposes the app architecture like:

```
 |__ my project
      |__ ...
      |__ main.js
      |__ package.json
      |__ index.html
      |__ ...
      |__ test
         |__ spec.js  <- You are here! ~ Well you should be.
```

but i don't have this architecture, instead, have the default architecture of electron-react boilerplate,my question here is how can i arrange this path for electron-react boilerplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to point it to the folder containing your Electron app js file entry point.

Here is a working sample with Electron 6:

https://github.com/florin05/electron-spectron-example